# Is it possible to include intellisense for the object global of globalsType in the RoslynPad RoslynCodeEditor control?

Tags: c#, roslyn, microsoft.codeanalysis, roslynpad

I've been working with the RoslynCodeEditor control and attempting to find a way to pass my globals object to the RoslynCodeEditor and have intellisense within my scripts.

Does anyone know how I can grant access to the context object properties or methods when editing my script using RoslynCodeEditor control?

```
MyContext context = new MyContext();
context.Data = data;
ScriptOptions scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default;
scriptOptions = scriptOptions.WithReferences(ReferencesAndImports.References);
scriptOptions = scriptOptions.WithImports(ReferencesAndImports.Imports);
var scriptState = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>("int i = 0;", scriptOptions, context, typeof(MyContext));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the globals type to the design-time compilation. To do that, you'll need a custom `RoslynHost` (supported in version 2.4 and up):

```
public class CustomRoslynHost : RoslynHost
{   
    protected override Project CreateProject(Solution solution, DocumentCreationArgs args, CompilationOptions compilationOptions, Project previousProject = null)
    {
        var name = args.Name ?? "Program";
        var id = ProjectId.CreateNewId(name);

        var parseOptions = new CSharpParseOptions(kind: SourceCodeKind.Script, languageVersion: LanguageVersion.Latest);

        compilationOptions = compilationOptions.WithScriptClassName(name);

        solution = solution.AddProject(ProjectInfo.Create(
            id,
            VersionStamp.Create(),
            name,
            name,
            LanguageNames.CSharp,
            isSubmission: true,
            parseOptions: parseOptions,
            hostObjectType: typeof(MyContext),
            compilationOptions: compilationOptions,
            metadataReferences: previousProject != null ? ImmutableArray<MetadataReference>.Empty : DefaultReferences,
            projectReferences: previousProject != null ? new[] { new ProjectReference(previousProject.Id) } : null));

        var project = solution.GetProject(id);

        return project;
    }
}
```

Then add a reference to the assembly the type resides in. For example:

```
new CutomRoslynHost(
    references: RoslynHostReferences.Default.With(
        typeNamespaceImports: new[] { typeof(MyContext) }),
    additionalAssemblies: ...);
```

Comment: Remember to make `MyContext` public, or it won't work.